# Замена view во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть вот такой фрагмент:

```
public class FotosFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "FotosFragment";

    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

    private static final String FOTO_ABSOLUT_PATH = "foto_absolut_path";
    private static final String FOTO_TYPE = "foto_type";
    private static final String FOTO_NUMBER = "foto_number";

    // типы файлов
    public static final int FOTO_FILE = 0;
    public static final int FOTO_ADD = 1;
    public static final int FOTO_NO = 2;

    private String mFotoAbsolutPath;
    private int mFotoType = 0;
    private int mFotoNumber = 0;

    private static Uri mFotoTempUri; // static - чтобы ссылка на фото не терялась при повороте экрана

    private ImageView ivFoto;
    private ProgressBar pbLoadFoto;
    private View mView;
    private ViewGroup mViewGroup;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private OnFotoListener mListener;

    private Context mContext;

    private LoadFotoTask mLoadFotoTask;

    public FotosFragment() {}

    public static FotosFragment newInstance(String fotoAbsolutPath, int fotoType, int fotoNumber) {
        FotosFragment fragment = new FotosFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(FOTO_ABSOLUT_PATH, fotoAbsolutPath);
        args.putInt(FOTO_TYPE, fotoType);
        args.putInt(FOTO_NUMBER, fotoNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }


    private Bitmap getBitmapSmall(File file){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Bitmap bmOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            // Вычисляем ширину и высоту изображения
            int width = bmOriginal.getWidth();
            int height = bmOriginal.getHeight();

            float ratioWidth = width / metrics.widthPixels;
            float ratioHeight = height / metrics.heightPixels;

            float ratio = ratioHeight < ratioWidth?ratioHeight:ratioWidth;

            int halfWidth = (int) (width / ratio);
            int halfHeight = (int) (height / ratio);

            Bitmap bmHalf = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmOriginal, halfWidth,
                    halfHeight, false);
            bmOriginal.recycle();
            return bmHalf;
        } return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mFotoAbsolutPath = getArguments().getString(FOTO_ABSOLUT_PATH);
            mFotoType = getArguments().getInt(FOTO_TYPE);
            mFotoNumber = getArguments().getInt(FOTO_NUMBER);
        }
    }


    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mFotoType == FOTO_ADD) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    ThingContent thingContent = ThingContent.get(mContext);
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File file = thingContent.getFotoDir();
                    if (!file.exists()) file.mkdirs();
                    file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath(), "IMG_" + Thing
                            .dateToString(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), Thing.DATE_FORMAT_FILE) + ".jpg");
                    mFotoTempUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFotoTempUri);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                }
            } else if (mFotoType == FOTO_FILE){
                startActivity(ViewFotoActivity.newIntent(mContext, mFotoAbsolutPath));
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mViewGroup = container;
        mInflater = inflater;
        mView = updateUI();
        return mView;
    }

    private View updateUI(){
        View view;
        switch (mFotoType) {
            case FOTO_FILE: {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fotos, null);
                ivFoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFoto);
                pbLoadFoto = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbLoadFoto);
                mLoadFotoTask = new LoadFotoTask();
                mLoadFotoTask.execute(mFotoAbsolutPath);
                break;
            }
            case FOTO_ADD: {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fotos_add, null);
                break;
            }
            case FOTO_NO: {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fotos_add, null);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fotos_add, null);
            }
        }
        ivFoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFoto);
        view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAttach " + this.toString());
        mContext = context;
        if (context instanceof OnFotoListener) mListener = (OnFotoListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDetach " + this.toString());
        mListener = null;
        if (mLoadFotoTask != null) {
            mLoadFotoTask.cancel(true);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Отмена потока");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult " + this.toString());
        if ((requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
            mFotoType = FOTO_FILE;
            mFotoAbsolutPath = mFotoTempUri.getEncodedPath();
            int index;
            if (mViewGroup != null) {
                if (mView != null) {
                    index = mViewGroup.indexOfChild(mView);
                    mViewGroup.removeViewInLayout(mView);
                    mView = updateUI();
                    mViewGroup.addView(mView, index);

                }
            }

            mListener.onClickFoto(mFotoAbsolutPath, mFotoNumber);

        } else mFotoTempUri = null;

    }

    public interface OnFotoListener {
        void onClickFoto(String fotoAbsolutPath, int position);
    }


    private class LoadFotoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
        private Bitmap mFotoBitmap;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbLoadFoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            try {
                pbLoadFoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.alpha_foto);
                ivFoto.startAnimation(anim);
                ivFoto.setImageBitmap(mFotoBitmap);
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            File fileFoto = new File(strings[0]);
            if (fileFoto.exists()) mFotoBitmap = getBitmapSmall(fileFoto);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

В методе `onActivityResult` пытаюсь поменять `view`, ошибки не выдает, но выводит белый экран. Когда в `onCreateView` создается `view`, то все-нормально.

P.S. Данный фрагмент используется для страниц `viewPager`

Вот мой адаптер:

```
private class AdapterPagerFoto extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        private List<String> mListFoto;
        private boolean mIsEdit;
        // listFoto - список полных путей к файлам фото
        // isEdit - true - режим редактирование и добавления
        //          false - режим просмотра
        public AdapterPagerFoto(FragmentManager fm, List<String> listFoto, boolean isEdit) {
            super(fm);
            mListFoto = listFoto;
            mIsEdit = isEdit;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;
            if (mIsEdit){
                if ((getCount()-1) == position){
                    fragment = FotosFragment.newInstance("", FotosFragment.FOTO_ADD, position);
                } else {
                   fragment =  FotosFragment.newInstance(mListFoto.get(position), FotosFragment.FOTO_FILE, position);
                }
            } else {
                if (mListFoto.size() == 0){
                   fragment = FotosFragment.newInstance("", FotosFragment.FOTO_NO, position);
                } else {
                   fragment = FotosFragment.newInstance(mListFoto.get(position), FotosFragment.FOTO_FILE, position);
                }
            }
            return fragment;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int result = 1;
            if (mIsEdit){
                result = mListFoto.size() + 1;
            }else {
                if (mListFoto.size() > 0) result = mListFoto.size();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
```

Comment: вы пытаетесь сделать что-то очень-очень странное. Используйте вместо этого просто другой фрагмент, а не пытайтесь заменить View данного фрагмента.

Comment: Да все вроде норм работает и фрагменты заменяются. Только вот когда переходит на новое активити, чтобы фото сделать, и перевернуть экран на новом активити, то при переходе обратно, фрагмент не заменяется на новый. Если экран не переворачивать, то нормально все. И когда не переходишь на новое активити, а просто переворачиваешь устройство, тоже норм.

Comment: Причем в `mListFoto` добавляется новый элемент, и вызов метода `notifyDataSetChanged` происходит.

Comment: Ну или может существует способ перезапустить фрагмент изнутри.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих мучений, так и не разобрался как поменять view. Проблему решил костылем. Сделал запуск метода `notifyDataSetChanged()` через 300 миллисекунд, и все заработало.

```
mHandler = new WeakHandler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mPagerFoto.setCurrentItem(positionFoto);
    }
}, 300);
```